# UWF: get CurrentEnabled value via VBS

Tags: windows, vbscript, uwf, uwfmgr

I'm trying to create a simple vbs script to get UWF status:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\StandardCimv2\embedded:UWF_Filter") 
WScript.Echo objWMIService.CurrentEnabled
```

The output is `null` even if I run it as administrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution: I've to look for the instances of UWF_Filter. This is the working code for UWF_filter

```vb
Set uwfFilters = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\StandardCimv2\embedded:UWF_Filter") 
Set oInstances = uwfFilters.instances_()

For Each oInstance In oInstances
    if oInstance.CurrentEnabled and oInstance.NextEnabled then
        Wscript.Echo "Enabled"
    elseif oInstance.CurrentEnabled and not oInstance.NextEnabled then
        Wscript.Echo "Enabled (will be disabled)"
    elseif not oInstance.CurrentEnabled and oInstance.NextEnabled then
        Wscript.Echo "Disabled (will be enabled)"
    else
        Wscript.Echo "Disabled"
    end if
Next
```

**Bonus point**: this script is intended for [BGInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/bginfo), so you need to replace `Wscript.Echo` with `Echo`.